# jQuery events and .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Never ran into this problem with jQuery before. I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#browser_cat a').click( function() {
        $('#browser_cat').hide();
        $('#browser_cat').load('/api/browser/catchildren/'+$(this).attr('id'));
        $('#browser_cat').fadeIn();
        return(false);
    })
});
```

Pretty simple stuff. And it works, however the data gathered by `.load()` doesn't retrigger the event. It is a drill-down category type thing ... so level-1 does the load but then leve-2 bails to the `href` rather than triggering the `click()` event again.

The loaded HTML is a `#browser_cat` with links, and the generated DOM is OK.

I appriciate this is elementary. Thanks in advance.

---

**Answer modified code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#browser_cat a').live("click", function() {
        $('#browser_cat').hide();
        $('#browser_cat').load('/api/browser/catchildren/'+$(this).attr('id'));
        $('#browser_cat').fadeIn();
        return(false);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** event

> Attach a handler to the event for all
>   elements which match the current
>   selector, now or in the future.

Replace

```
$('#browser_cat a').click( function() {
```

with

```
$('#browser_cat a').live("click", function() {
```

Comment: +1 and accept. Thanks rahul. Just what I was after; I think I should RTFM. I also think I should update jQuery from 1.2.3 :S